# free memory allotted to 3D matrix

Tags: c, memory-management

I allocate memory for 3D matrix by the following code.

```
double ***AllocMatrix3(short nrh, short nch, short nph)
{
  short i,j,k;
  double ***m;

   m=(double ***) malloc(nrh* sizeof(double***));

  for(i=0;i<=nrh;i++) {
    m[i]=(double **) malloc(nch*sizeof(double*));
    for (j=0;j<=nch;j++){
        m[i][j]=(double*) malloc(nph*sizeof(double));
    }
  }
  for(k=0;k<=nph;k++)
  for(i=0;i<=nrh;i++)
    for(j=0;j<=nch;j++)
         m[i][j][k] = 0.0;
  return m; 
}
```

but when I try to free the memory using the code below it doesn't work

```
void FreeMatrix3(double ***m,short nrl,short nrh,
                short ncl,short nch, short npl,short nph)
{
  short i,j,k;

  for(i=nrh;i>=0;i--)
    for(j=nch;j>=0;j--) 
        free((m[i][j]));
    free(m[i]);
}
```

can you please help.
Thanks in Advance.
Vijitha

Comment: Shouldn't you also do `free(m)` at the bottom? What error are you getting?

Comment: `free(m[i])` is not inside the loop `for(i=nrh;i>=0;i--)`. Use `{` and `}` to put it in scope.

Comment: `for(i=0;i<=nrh;i++)` will iterate `nrh + 1` times, not `nrh` times

Comment: @BryanOlivier Thank you. This is why loop and `if` bodies should *always* be compound statements.

Comment: Although this works: `m=(double ***) malloc(nrh* sizeof(double***));`, it's **not** correct, as it shall be `...malloc(nrh * sizeof(double**));`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `malloc` and later setting the values to `0` you can use `calloc` for the final allocation (at the `double` level).

The line `m=(double ***) malloc(nrh* sizeof(double***));` will allocate room for `nrh` elements but you later iterate with `for(i=0;i<=nrh;i++)` which iterates `nrh + 1` times.
You need to either change the call to `malloc` or the `for`.

For the `free`, you need to:

- `free` `m[i][j]` for all i and j
- `free` `m[i]` for all i
- `free` `m`

Basically, you should always add accolades to your `for` statements. It helps prevent such issues.

Also, do you really need jagged arrays and returning `double***`? You might be able to so the same thing by returning `calloc( nrh * nch * nph, sizeof(double) )` which you can then free with a single call to `free`.

Caveat, the part about `calloc` might not always apply to floating point values. It should always apply to integral types though.

Answer (score 1):

there are 3 problems in your code:

1. off by one error in every for loop you have. use the `<` instead of `<=` for the incrementing loops and set the initial value to `j=nch-1` for the decrementing loops
2. bad brace scope in the fee code as mentioned in the comments

   ```
   for(i=nrh;i>=0;i--){
       for(j=nch;j>=0;j--) 
           free((m[i][j]));
       free(m[i]);
   }
   ```
3. you don't free m itself